# Expression for Row Visibility when FALSE is “” or NOTHING? (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following expression in a cell:

```
=IIF(last(Fields!OpenedEmail.Value) >= (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -30, Parameters!end_date.Value)), last(Fields!OpenedEmail.Value), "")
```

I’m having problems figuring out what expression I need to put into the Row Visibility to get the row to disappear if "" or NOTHING is used for FALSE. I’ve tried combinations of IIF, SWITCH, and ISNOTHING but no dice.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the row when the expression is blank, you would put the TRUE to hide the row where you currently have the blank:

```
=IIF(last(Fields!OpenedEmail.Value) >= (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -30, Parameters!end_date.Value)), False, True)
```

Comment: So a couple of things, I need "last(Fields!OpenedEmail.Value)" within the expression and if I am to put "True" where I have "", what am I putting in the ISNOTHING expression because I'm not getting the row to disappear with that suggestion also.

Comment: @CodingGirl963 - I thought you needed an expression for the Row Visibility (Hidden property) and not the cell Value.